# If $AB$ and $BA$ are defined, then $AB$ and $BA$ are square matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

So as self-practice, I'm going over some proofs from Linear Algebra. I came across the following proof:

$$\text{Prove that if both products $AB$ and $BA$ are defined, then $AB,BA \in M_{n,n}$.}$$

I doubted my ability of proving the statement directly, so I resorted to the contrapositive:

$$\text{If $AB, BA \not\in M_{n,n}$, then $AB, BA$ aren't defined.}$$
Or equivalently, $$\text{If $AB, BA \in M_{n,m}, n \neq m$, then $AB, BA$ aren't defined.}$$

$Proof:$ Let $AB, BA \in M_{n,m}, n\neq m$. Then, $$AB \to (n\times \underbrace{m) \times (n}_{n\neq m} \times m) \;\Rightarrow\; AB \text{ is undef.}$$
and
$$BA \to (n\times \underbrace{m) \times (n}_{n\neq m} \times m) \;\Rightarrow\; BA \text{ is undef.} \tag{$\blacksquare$}$$

I wanted to ask if my assumption for the contrapositive was valid, and/or if there are any cases I'm missing? For one, I struggled with the concept of what it means for a matrix product to be defined. Visually above, I know that if the inner two numbers don't match, then the product is undefined. This is why I felt it was sufficient to just show that in the contrapositive proof, whereas in the proof of the statement directly, I felt that using this model was $not$ sufficient (rigorous enough).

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The first assertion is false as stated: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}=[2]\in M_{1,1}\;,$$ and $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\in M_{2,2}\;.$$ Perhaps you mean that if both products are defined, then both products are square (but not necessarily of the same size).

Comment: That's actually a great observation. I did mean that they are square but I never considered the limit of such notation. Noted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $m' \times n'$ matrix.

Then if $AB$ is defined, means $n=m'$ and $AB\in M_{m\times n'}$ and if $BA$ if defined, then $n'=m$ $BA\in m'\times m $.

So it means if $A\in M_{m\times n}$ and $B\in M_{n\times m}$.

Now $AB\in M_{m\times m}$ and $BA\in M_{n\times n}$

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be $i\times j$ and let $B$ be $k\times\ell$. Then
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
AB\text{ defined} &\Leftrightarrow& j=k &&& & BA\text{ defined} &\Leftrightarrow&\ell=i
\end{array}
Thus $B$ is $j\times i$. Hence
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
AB\text{ is }i\times i & & & & BA\text{ is } j\times j
\end{array}